# EMR Hadoop Pig job error "Internal error creating job configuration"

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, emr

I have a PIG job running on Amazon EMR and suddnly it has stopped working giving the following error:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:855)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:294)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1264)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1249)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1239)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:333)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:479)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.adjustNumReducers(JobControlCompiler.java:875)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:480)
    ... 17 more
================================================================================
```

Does anyone know why or what might be the problem? this is one of the most vague errors I have ever seen.

Comment: share the pig script, it's happening while adjusting the number of reducers.. so could you check once with 1 reducer and let us know the output..

Comment: Believe it or not, it was unable to find one of the input files to be processed.... they need to work on their error logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem actually turned out to be that PIG was unable to locate one of the input files to be processed, yet the error doesn't even remotely suggest a missing file issue.